# "Save config" in rviz doesn't work on OSX

Tags: rviz, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally I've managed to get ros fuerte working on OSX. Still there's a bug when saving the config with default extension `.vcd` within rviz. Starting rviz, it loads the config file `~/.rviz/display_config` by default. When I use "save config", I'm not able to write `~/.rviz/display_config`. Instead, the file is saved as `~/.rviz/display_config.vcg`.

In my opinion, the correct default file should use the `.vcg` extension. Any other opinions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37433/%22save-config%22-in-rviz-doesn%27t-work-on-osx/) by [tschamm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2481/tschamm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-06-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Whatever the correct solution, this looks like a bug.

Please [open a defect ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/newticket?component=visualization&type=defect&&visualization) to get it fixed.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1